# What's the difference in usage for 'there's a time' vs. 'there's time' vs. 'there's the time'?

Tags: time

What's the difference in usage for 'there's a time' vs. 'there's time' vs. 'there's the time'?
Is the last one even correct?

Similarly, what's the difference between 'it was a time' vs. 'it was the time' vs. 'it was time'?

I suspect the last one is only used in fixed expressions like 'it's high time' etc. but I'm not sure of anything anymore.

Answer (score 1):

There's a time and a place for everything.

There's time to get a cup of coffee before we have to leave.

(I can't think of a context for *there's the time.*)

It was a time of great hardship.

It was the time of year when...

It was time to say goodbye.

Comment: Can we try some generalization, then: 'a time' - a specific period/moment in time now or in the past; 'there's time' and 'it's time' - we're basically talking about the clock and what the time is; and... what about 'the time'? Is it only in expressions like 'the time of the year', 'the time of the month' etc.?

Comment: _There's time_ = there's enough time.  I suppose you could use _it was the time_ of historical periods - 'It was the time when crinolines were coming into fashion'. C.f. the famous opening paragraph of Dickens' _A Tale of Two Cities_ 'It was the best of times, it was the worst of times...'

Comment: Yeah, but _the best/ the worst of times_ seems just a plural of _a time_ in the sense of being a specific period of time. I agree with 'the time' example which sounds alright to me. But then again, there seems to be no clear difference between _the time_ and _a time_ when it comes to usage.

Comment: The difference is between _the time_ when a specific thing was happening, and _a time_ , say, of hardship, which was one of many such times.

Comment: OK, it's clear now. Thank you!

Comment: (Looks at a clock.) "*Oh, look. There's **the** time.*"

Comment: Hahah, that's perfect! Thanks, Jason!